# How to assign a variable for each group of a duplicate column based on date column checking by date difference with preceding row in r?

Tags: python, r

I am a newbie to R and to post questions as well. Apologies for any errors/comments.
I have a data frame as below:
[image: Data frame]

I am looking to get something like this:
[image: Output]

Description: For each unique "ID" check if the "Date" difference with the preceding row is > 1 year. If > 1 year then output "R", else "F". For the first time it should be "FT". 
Is there a way to do this using R/Python?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please update your question with original dataset posted using `dput()` function as we can use images.

Comment: can you also post the code which you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you. -

Comment: @Sunny [Edit] your question. Don't try and write code in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straight forward methodology is to calculate the time difference and use an `ifelse` statement to create your expected variable. Using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = '%d-%m-%Y')) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(temp = c(0, diff.difftime(Date)), Status = ifelse(temp > 365, 'R', 
                                                   ifelse(temp == 0, 'FT', 'F'))) %>% 
 select(-temp)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 3
> # Groups:   ID [4]
>       ID Date                Status
>    <dbl> <dttm>              <chr> 
>  1   101 2016-04-10 00:00:00 FT    
>  2   101 2017-05-10 00:00:00 R     
>  3   101 2017-05-15 00:00:00 F     
>  4   101 2018-05-20 00:00:00 R     
>  5   102 2016-04-10 00:00:00 FT    
>  6   103 2016-04-01 00:00:00 FT    
>  7   103 2016-04-10 00:00:00 F     
>  8   103 2018-05-10 00:00:00 R     
>  9   104 2016-04-10 00:00:00 FT    
> 10   104 2017-05-10 00:00:00 R
> ```

**DATA:**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 103, 103, 103, 
104, 104), Date = c("10-04-2016", "10-05-2017", "15-05-2017", 
"20-05-2018", "10-04-2016", "01-04-2016", "10-04-2016", "10-05-2018", 
"10-04-2016", "10-05-2017")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: one more question: can we write the output to a csv file??

Comment: Sure. Check out the function `write.csv()`